# jQuery show/hide options if button selected two options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, select

By default selected AUTO category - its ok.

But I want that make and serie should be **Not selected** - by default.

When I change category from AUTO to MOTO still should be not selected make and serie with empty **Not selected** - value. Than if I select make, serie should be  with empty **Not selected** - value.

I placed my code here what I have for now:

```js
var $clonedOpts = $("#make_select").children().clone();

$(".tab a").click(function() { 
  var $layOpts = $clonedOpts.clone().filter('[value^=' + $(this).data("val") + ']');
  $("#make_select").html($layOpts);
});
$(".tab a").eq(0).click();



 $(document).ready(function() {
  var optarray = $("#serie_select").children('option').map(function() {
   var selected = '';
   if($(this).attr('selected')){
    selected = "selected='"+ $(this).attr('selected')+"'";
   }
   return {
    "value": this.value,
    "option": "<option value='" + this.value + "' "+selected+" >" + this.text + "</option>"
   }
  })

  $("#make_select").change(function() {
   $("#serie_select").children('option').remove();
   var addoptarr = [];
   for (i = 0; i < optarray.length; i++) {
    if (optarray[i].value.indexOf($(this).val()) > -1) {
     addoptarr.push(optarray[i].option);
    }
   }
   $("#serie_select").html(addoptarr.join(''))
  }).change();
 })
```

```css
 a:hover {
  cursor:pointer;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab">
  Choose category:<br>
  <a data-val="auto">AUTO</a> / <a data-val="moto">MOTO</a>
</div>
<br>

Make:
<select id="make_select">
  <option value="">Not selected</option>
  <option value="auto_audi">AUDI</option>
  <option value="auto_bmw">BMW</option>
  
  <option value="moto_kawasaki">Kawasaki</option>
  <option value="moto_harley-davidson">Harley Davidson</option>
</select>


Serie:
<select id="serie_select">
  <option value="">Not selected</option>
  <option value="auto_audi_a6">A6</option>
  <option value="auto_audi_a8">A8</option>
  <option value="auto_bmw_x3">X3</option>
  <option value="auto_bmw_x5">X6</option>

  <option value="moto_kawasaki_ninja">Ninja</option>
  <option value="moto_kawasaki_z900">Z900</option>
  <option value="moto_harley-davidson_street-750">Street 750</option>
  <option value="moto_harley-davidson_sportster-1200">Sportster 1200</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Can you explain more about your request?

Comment: Hello,
I want to do that MAKE and SERIE should be not selected in options.

It should be choosed manually.

Comment: we want change html code?

Comment: It can be changed.

Comment: Can I re-code your idea ?

Comment: If you have any solutions. Please you can do.

Comment: Okay, wait me a minute ^^

Comment: you need to  select by default Not selected in both case(AUTO/MOTO) right ?

Comment: @KalpeshDabhi yes, should be in both as default Non selected.

Answer (score 0):

My solution for you. You can add data easily !

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab">
  Choose category:<br>
  <a class="clickChoice" data-val="auto">AUTO</a> / <a class="clickChoice" data-val="moto">MOTO</a>
</div>
<br>

Make:
<select id="make_select">
  <option value="">Not selected</option>
</select>


Serie:
<select id="serie_select">
  <option>Not selected</option>
</select>


<script>
 var main_category = ["auto", "moto"];
 var makeArr = [];
 makeArr['auto'] = ["audi", "bmw"];
 makeArr['moto'] = ["kawwa", "honda"];
 
 var serieArr  = [];
 serieArr['audi'] = ["X1", "X2"];
 serieArr['bmw'] = ["N1", "N2"];
 
 serieArr['kawwa'] = ["Ninja1000", "NinjaH2"];
 serieArr['honda'] = ["CBR1000", "CBR250"];
 
 
 
 
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".clickChoice").click(function(k){
   var category = $(this).data("val");
   var makeList = makeArr[category]; 
   
   $('#make_select')
    .find('option')
    .remove()
    .end()
    .append("<option>Select value</option>")
    ;
   makeList.forEach(function(x) {
    $('#make_select').append("<option value="+x+">"+x.toUpperCase()+"</option>");
   });
   
  });
  
  $('#make_select').on('change', function() {
   var makeValue = this.value;
   var serieList = serieArr[makeValue];
   console.log(makeValue);
   $('#serie_select')
    .find('option')
    .remove()
    .end()
    .append("<option>Select value</option>")    
    ;
   serieList.forEach(function(x) {
    $('#serie_select').append("<option value="+x+">"+x.toUpperCase()+"</option>");
   });
  });
  
  
 })
 
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, its looks much better than my code.

But I take all makes from this code:
`<?php $terms = get_terms( 'make', array( 'hide_empty' => false, ) ); foreach ( $terms as $term ) { echo '"'.$term->slug.'",'; } ?>`


and all series from this code:
`<?php $terms = get_terms( 'series', array( 'hide_empty' => false, ) ); foreach ( $terms as $term ) { echo '"'.$term->slug.'",'; } ?>`

How I should implement into your code?

Comment: Can you capture your code ^^ It look too hard to see :D

Comment: I can share but I dont know or you will understand :D
Here link to my code: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/beauto/L9dt6af7/1/)

Comment: what is it ? $term->slug. I think it will be great if you can show me your database. I think we should make a chat converstation :D

Comment: Its wordpress terms, taxonomies. 
Where I can write you?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I need to see output of $term => slug